# Regarding the development of random color chip placement buttons

Tags: javascript, html, css, random

There was a problem while developing 'Color Chip Random Placement Button', which is the main function of the website I am developing.

**The function of the ‘color chip random placement button’ is to show or hide small squares placed in random locations.**

There was a problem while applying the media query code for the mobile screen. For mobile design reasons, I have created another button that can only be seen on the mobile screen. For this reason, there is a problem that small square color chips are not placed in random locations.

**The button is functionally normal Only when the mobile screen ratio. And the function does not work when the desktop ratio. If I press the button on the desktop ratio, the small squares are located at the top.**

Before you give me your answer, I appreciate your help in advance.

And since I'm not a coding expert, I'd really appreciate it if you could give me a specific answer with a specific code.

I attach the design draft before and after pressing the color chip random placement button. I'd appreciate it if you could refer to the image and help me with coding.

[image]
[image]

```js
            const btn = document.querySelector("button");
            const height = document.documentElement.clientHeight;
            const width = document.documentElement.clientWidth;
            const boxes = document.querySelectorAll(".random");

            btn.addEventListener("click", () => {
              Array.from(boxes).forEach(box => {
                const top = Math.floor(Math.random() * (height - 30) + 1) + "px";
                const right = Math.floor(Math.random() * (width - 30) + 1) + "px";

                box.style.top = top;
                box.style.right = right;
              })
            });

            function showhide() {
              var x = document.querySelectorAll(".random");
              var i;
              for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
                if (x[i].style.display === "block") {
                  x[i].style.display = "none";
                } else {
                  x[i].style.display =
                    "block";
                }
              }
            }

            //draggable

            function mouseDown(downEvent) {
              var box = downEvent.srcElement;
              var offX = box.getBoundingClientRect().left - downEvent.x;
              var offY = box.getBoundingClientRect().top - downEvent.y;
              document.onmousemove = e => {
                box.style.top = Math.min(Math.max(e.y + offY, 0), height) + "px";
                box.style.left = Math.min(Math.max(e.x + offX, 0), width) + "px";
              }
              document.onmouseup = e => {
                document.onmousemove = document.onmouseup = null;
              }
              return false;
            }

            Array.from(boxes).forEach(box => {
              box.onmousedown = mouseDown;
            })


            //호버 혹은 클릭 시, div 컬러 변화
            
            $(".music").hover(
                function() {
                    $(this).addClass("hover");
                }, function() {
                    $(this).removeClass("hover");
                }
            );

            $(".music").click(function() {
                $('#result').load('album_list_index.php');
                $(".music").removeClass("active");
                $(this).removeClass("hover").addClass("active");
            });
```

```css
        body{margin-top: 0px; margin-right: 0px; margin-left: 0px;}

        /*호버 메뉴 컬러 변화*/
        .active { background: #edd6bc }
        .hover { background: #edd6bc }


        button {position: relative; width: 30px; height: 30px; background: #edd6bc; border: none; }
        .random {position: absolute; width: 30px; height: 30px; cursor: move;}

        .container {
          display: grid;
          grid-template-columns: 1fr;
          grid-template-rows: 1fr;
        }

        header {
          display: grid;
          grid-template-columns: 1fr 7fr;
          grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr;
          grid-template-areas: "logo nav" "logo notice";
        }

        .logo {
          grid-area: logo;
          padding: 10px;
          text-align: center;
          border-bottom: 1px solid black;
        }

        .notice {
          grid-area: notice;
          padding: 10px;
        }

        main {
          display: grid;
          grid-template-columns: repeat(8, 1fr);
          grid-template-rows: repeat(8, 1fr);
        }

        main>div {
          padding: 10px;
          text-align: center;
        }

        nav {
          display: grid;
          grid-template-columns: repeat(7, 1fr);
          grid-area: nav;
        }

        nav a {
          padding: 10px;
          text-align: center;
        }

        /*shop과 서브메뉴 드랍*/

        li {    
          border-right: 1px solid black;    
          text-align: center;
          background-color: white;
          padding: 37px;
        }

        nav ul{
            list-style: none;
        }
        
        nav ul li {
            display: inline-block;
            list-style-type: none;
        }

        nav li > ul{
            display : none;
        }

        nav li > ul li{
            display: block;
        }

        nav  li > ul li a {
            color: #111;
            display: block;
            line-height: 2em;
            padding: 0.5em 2em;
            text-decoration: none;
        }

        nav li:hover {
            background-color: #edd6bc;
        }
        
        nav li:hover > ul{
            position: absolute;
            display : block;
        }


        li.music {
          list-style: none;
        }

        .sub_nav{
            width: 100%; 
            border: 1px solid black;
            }


        .replat_mobile {
            display: none;
        }



        @media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
        
            
            .gone{display: none;}
              
            nav{width: 100vw;}
              
            .replat_mobile {
                clear: both;
                display: block;
                float: left;
                margin-left: 0px;
                width: 10px;          
            }


            .container {
              display: grid;
              grid-template-columns: 1fr;
              grid-template-rows: 1fr;
            }

            header {
              display: grid;
              grid-template-columns: 1fr 3fr;
              grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr;
              grid-template-areas: "logo nav" "logo notice";
            }

            nav {
              display: grid;
              grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
              grid-area: nav;
            }

            .notice {
              grid-area: notice;
              padding: 10px;
            }

            nav a {
              padding: 10px;
              text-align: center;
            }

            main {
              display: grid;
              grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
              grid-template-rows: repeat(4, 1fr);
            }

            main>div {
              padding: 10px;
              text-align: center;
            }


        }
```

```html
<div class="container">


        <div class="replat_mobile" >
          <nav>
            
            <a style="background-color: red;">
                <button style="margin: auto;" onclick="showhide()" value="Zeige Features" id="button"></button> 
            </a>
            
            <a style="background-color: yellow;"> 
                <img style="height: calc(20vw - 50px);" src="https://cdn.imweb.me/upload/S202106158a019d8d01cb9/2b23eb2d2e178.jpg"> 
            </a>
            
            <a style="background-color: blue;"> Eng </a>
          </nav>
        </div>

        <header>
          
          <div class="logo gone" style="border-right: 1px solid black;">Logo</div>
          
          <nav>

            <li class="music" style="border-right: 1px solid black;">
                <a href="#" class="music" style="background-color: yellow;">About</a>
            </li>
            
            <li class="music" style="border-right: 1px solid black;">
                <a href="#" class="music" style="background-color: yellow;">Exibition</a>
            </li>

            <li class="music">
                <a href="#" class="music" style="background-color: yellow;">Shop</a>
                <ul>
                <li a href="#" class="sub_nav" style="margin-top: 35px; ">리플랫</li>
                <li a href="#" class="sub_nav" style="margin-top: 13px; ">작품</li>
                <li a href="#" class="sub_nav" style="margin-top: 13px; ">MD</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            
            <a class="gone"></a>
            <a class="gone"></a>
            
            <a href="#" class="gone" style="border-left: 1px solid black;" >
                <button style="margin: auto;" onclick="showhide()" value="Zeige Features" id="button" class="gone"></button>
            </a>
            <a href="#" class="gone music" style="border-left: 1px solid black;">Eng</a>
          </nav>
          
          <div class="notice" style="border-top: 1px solid black; border-bottom: 1px solid black;" >Space for Notice</div>
        
        </header>
        

        <!--전시 컬러칩-->

        <div a href="#" style="display: none; background: #6d97b4;" class="random" ></div>
            
        <div a href="#" style="display: none; background: #c9656f;" class="random" ></div>
            
        <div a href="#" style="display: none; background: #f1eb40;" class="random" ></div>
            
        <div a href="#" style="display: none; background: #00825c;" class="random" ></div>
            
        <div a href="#" style="display: none; background: #009ce0;" class="random" ></div>
            
        <div a href="#" style="display: none; background: #cee4a6;" class="random" ></div>
```

Comment: Please could you put your code into a working snippet in your question and try it out. I cannot see that the layout changes on smaller viewports with the code you have given. Also perhaps try to simplify your question and the associated code so it is asking one question, not several.

Comment: It appears to work fine, hiding/showing the squares when clicking the button, in both modes. One thing is that you only randomize the positions once, on page load. If you do not reload the page, the positions do not get updated. Due to this, if you resize the page from mobile to desktop without reloading, it could appear that the squares are clustered in a small area of the view.

Comment: I summarized the coding problem more succinctly. It was then modified to allow code snippets to view the code. Thank you so much for trying to help me with my coding problem. Please check my code and leave any other questions or inconveniences.